# How do I create a config file for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I generally use phpMyAdmin on a server where it is already installed. However, I now have the task of providing a config file for an installation of phpMyAdmin.

I have the server name, username and password. I also have created the config directory inside of the phpMyAdmin directory.

I could use some help with the basic file content. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't pma have this new config thingy that automatically generates config files...? Can't check right now but I've seen it in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be a file called config.sample.inc.php in your phpmyadmin folder - simply copy it to config.inc.php and edit it to suit your needs

Comment: That was a lot easier than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: I have a cheapo cpanel web hosting account and can't see my phpmyadmin folder - do I still have the option of creating this file elsewhere?