# how to install new version of phpmyadmin to a server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Built-in phpmyadmin on control panel of my domain is old version so I wanted to change it to new one. I uploaded new version of phpmyadmin through ftp (folder: mydomain.com/phpmyadmin). Previously, I changed config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php and added random string value in field $cfg['blowfish_secret']. 
Now, I cannot login in phpmyadmin and I cannot find which username to use(tried 'root',admin etc...). Whatever I enter in login form i receive error message "Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

I know that It is a problem between phpmyadmin and MySQL, and I don't know what to do next?

Comment: How did you access the old version provided by your host -- any chance it was the same URL? If the URL conflicts, you might have problems; better to install to a new folder with a different URL than the provided version.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade phpmyadmin, you have to conduct 6 steps:

- find your version
- find your phpmyadmin directory
- copy your configuration file
- download the newest version of phpmyadmin
- put the new files in place
- add your config file

[Source](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/).

If you have the config file, then you can solve your problem by following the steps. If you no longer have the config file, then you need to create a config file. To do that, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142425/how-do-i-create-a-config-file-for-phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the secret key, you will have to make sure that the root username and password are entered into your config.inc.php, by default the codings are not there, you have to add them in manually, please refer to below URL (last step) for the code. This apply to both linux and windows server.

http://boxtutor.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-in-linux-servers/

Comment: By default the `auth_type` is cookie, which means you do not need to enter your username and password in `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0):

> Whatever I enter in login form i receive error message "Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

Which is almost certainly caused by

> I cannot find which username to use(tried 'root',admin etc...).

You'll need to find your username and password to log in. If you're not sure, ask your hosting provider for assistance with this. It's not something we can help you figure out since it's your login information.

Once you find those, you should be able to enter them directly in the phpMyAdmin login box (provided that you haven't changed the `auth_type` from the default of 'cookie', which is what I use).